# Is it possible to query a table using ALL_TABLES to get a count - ORACLE

Tags: oracle, count

I need a faster way to count certain records in a large table of over 11 billions rows.
I run below query and it gets the count in 1 second of 11 + billion rows

```
SELECT a.TABLE_NAME, to_char ( a.NUM_ROWS ), b.COLUMN_NAME
FROM ALL_TABLES a, ALL_TAB_COLUMNS b
WHERE a.table_name = 'OBJECT_TABLE' 
and a.TABLE_NAME = b.TABLE_NAME 
and b.owner = 'XX_ST'
and b.COLUMN_NAME = 'OBJECT_TYPE'
```

Result is this OBJECT_TABLE  11042049900 OBJECT_TYPE

I want to query the OBJECT_TABLE and only get certain OBJECT_TYPES not all.
If I run query like this it takes a really long time

```
SELECT count (*)
FROM OBJECT_TABLE a
WHERE a.OBJECT_TYPE in ( 425, 989 ).
```

From this query, I would expect 100,000 of the 11 + billion rows.

Is there a way to use the ALL_TABLES a, ALL_TAB_COLUMNS b to make the query run faster to ONLY get certain rows but not all of a certain table?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: The num_rows value in the all_tables view comes from running statistics on the table. It is unlikely to be correct (unless maybe you've just gathered stats on the table sampling 100% of the rows), and shouldn't be relied on (unless maybe the data in the table never changes, which seems... unlikely). You might have better luck adding an index on object_type if you want to speed up the select count(*) query

Comment: Why do you need the `count(*)`? To show *you are on the 1st page of 11.000.000.000*? For this purposes an *approximate count* is sufficient, which *could be* provided by the object statistics from `ALL_TABLES`.

Comment: I want the count of specific TYPES of records.to know that eventually I will need to start deleting which will give a rough estimate of how long the delete process will take.  The different TYPES of records can be anywhere in the 11+ billion rows.

Comment: Do you need an exact count? What is this number being used for? Depending on your business use case, partitioning might be something to look at. And, how often does this table change - how volatile is it?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is not logically possible.  The only way to get an actual count is to query the data.  If using Enterprise Edition then applying parallelism to the count query to improve its performance may be a possibility.  Otherwise you are left with using some type of estimate. In the mentioned case where if you just need to know if any rows exist that meet the condition then an EXISTS sub-query can be used.  An EXISTS terminates upon finding the first match which is usually much faster than having to run the complete sub-query as when no match is found.